# PYGAME Moving an object while having others move

Tags: python, oop, object, pygame, sprite

Right now i have it so that a few objects will scroll accross the screen at different times and speeds, as well as a icon (hero) i can control with my arrow keys. However whenever I press a key, the icon returns to his original position. What could be causing this?

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
winW = 800
winH = 500
surface = pygame.display.set_mode ((winW, winH),0,32)

class Enemy():
    def __init__(self, char, xMoveAmnt, startY=0, startX=0, delay=0):
        self.char = char
        self.delay=delay
        self.x = startX
        self.y = startY
        self.startX=startX
        self.startY=startY
        self.xMoveAmnt = xMoveAmnt
        self.image = pygame.image.load(self.char)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


    def moveChar(self):
        if self.delay > 0:
             self.delay -= 1
             return
        self.x += self.xMoveAmnt
        if self.x + self.rect.right >= 800:
            self.x=self.startX
            self.y=random.randint(0,300)

class FastEnemy(Enemy):
    def moveChar(self):
        if self.delay > 0:
             self.delay -= 1
             return
        self.x += self.xMoveAmnt+10
        if self.x + self.rect.right >= 800:
            self.x=self.startX
            self.y=random.randint(0,300)

class SlowEnemy(Enemy):       
    def moveChar(self):
        if self.delay > 0:
             self.delay -= 1
             return
        self.x += self.xMoveAmnt-5
        if self.x + self.rect.right >= 800:
            self.x=self.startX
            self.y=random.randint(0,300)

class Hero():
    def __init__(self):
        self.X_MOVE_AMT = 5
        self.Y_MOVE_AMT = 5
        self.spaceMoveX = 0 
        self.spaceMoveY = 0
        self.startingX=400
        self.startingY=250
        self.x=self.startingX
        self.y=self.startingY
        self.space = pygame.image.load ("hero_sprite.jpg")
        self.spaceRect = self.space.get_rect()
        self.spaceRect.topleft = (100,100)

    def moveHero(self):


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_LEFT :
                    self.x += -(self.X_MOVE_AMT)
                    self.y = 0
                if event.key == K_RIGHT :
                    self.x += self.X_MOVE_AMT
                    self.y = 0
                if event.key == K_UP :
                    self.y += -(self.Y_MOVE_AMT)
                    self.x = 0
                if event.key == K_DOWN :
                    self.y += self.Y_MOVE_AMT
                    self.x = 0
                if event.key == ord (' '):
                    self.y = 0
                    self.x = 0
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit ()
                    sys.exit()

        self.spaceRect.top += self.spaceMoveY
        self.spaceRect.left += self.spaceMoveX

        if self.spaceRect.top < 0:
            self.spaceRect.top = 0

        if self.spaceRect.bottom > 500:
            self.spaceRect.bottom = 500

        if self.spaceRect.left < 0:
            self.spaceRect.left = 0

        if self.spaceRect.right > 800:
            self.spaceRect.right = 800



enemyList = []
hero=Hero()
for i in range (0, 8):
    xMoveAmnt=20
    enemyList.append(SlowEnemy(("orc3.png"), xMoveAmnt, random.randint(0, 500), 0, random.randint(0,100)))
    enemyList.append(Enemy(("orc.png"), xMoveAmnt, random.randint(0, 500), 0, random.randint(0,100)))
    enemyList.append(FastEnemy(("orc2.png"), xMoveAmnt, random.randint(0, 500), 0, random.randint(0,100)))

while True:
    surface.fill ((255,255,255))
    for enemy in enemyList:
        enemy.moveChar()
        hero.moveHero()
        surface.blit(enemy.image, (enemy.x, enemy.y))
        surface.blit(hero.space, (hero.x, hero.y))
        time.sleep(00.01)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            if event.key == K_LEFT :
                self.x += -(self.X_MOVE_AMT)
                self.y = 0
            if event.key == K_RIGHT :
                self.x += self.X_MOVE_AMT
                self.y = 0
            if event.key == K_UP :
                self.y += -(self.Y_MOVE_AMT)
                self.x = 0
            if event.key == K_DOWN :
                self.y += self.Y_MOVE_AMT
                self.x = 0
            if event.key == ord (' '):
                self.y = 0
                self.x = 0
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit ()
                sys.exit()
```

Needed to be

```
            if event.key == K_LEFT :
                self.x += -(self.X_MOVE_AMT)
            if event.key == K_RIGHT :
                self.x += self.X_MOVE_AMT
            if event.key == K_UP :
                self.y += -(self.Y_MOVE_AMT)
            if event.key == K_DOWN :
                self.y += self.Y_MOVE_AMT
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit ()
                sys.exit()
```

I was resetting the Y and X everytime i pressed a button. Sorry for wasting your time!